# Android: Is there a way to enable WI-FI in Progressive app architecture

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I was starting to develop a mobile app and get to look into Progressive app architecture.

The concept of taking best of App and best of Web seems good.
But in my case I have to play with wifi connections.

**Is there a way to handle connect, disconnect, check network details and all other Wi-Fi stuff?**

While working with progressive web apps we get to user service workers for network calls

is there kind of tools OR libraries OR service-workers to support Wi-Fi and Data connectivity things with progressive web apps

**Note**: Progressive web app's code is written in javascript. [Take a look](http://blog.ionic.io/what-is-a-progressive-web-app/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Network API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) to detect the current state of the network connection on a device (very roughly) but that's it I'm afraid.

If you want to be able to explicitly look for and connect to Wifi networks you need to write a native app (assuming the particular in question offers those API's).

Answer (score 0):

I try to check in W3C no one talking about advance WIFI API on the web in this time. Just only Network API follow above answer